# How to form a tuple from a tuple of tuple using scala?

Tags: scala, collections, apache-spark

My input is , And it is in the form of RDD[((Int,(String,String)),Int)]

```
((0,(sunny,no)),3)
((0,(sunny,yes)),2)
((0,(overcast,yes)),4)
((0,(rainy,yes)),3)
((0,(rainy,no)),2)
```

I want the output as,

```
(3,2)
(4)
(3,2)
```

Comment: What is the type of result? `RDD[(String, Any)]`?

Comment: Or maybe `RDD[(String, Seq[Int])]`?

Comment: I need to take both values for the next step.I thnk the type doesn't make any pblm...

Comment: you should not use tuples as lists.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
val data: RDD[((Int,(String,String)),Int)] = ???

val treated = data.groupBy(_._1._2._1).map(_._2.map(_._2))
```

This will give you an `RDD[(String, Iterable[Int])]` in the form you want.

Comment: BUt If we use groupBY, If large data comes,It won't work or the system may be stuck

Comment: @rosy, if you want to group together all "sunny" items as your question suggests, you have no choice but to read all your input. This answer does collect all the data of each row, but that's not a lot more. If you want a minimal version, convert each item to just the sunny/overcast/rain and the last value and then groupBy - - but you're sill going to store something for every item in the data, because that's inherent in your question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Spark can implement `groupBy` efficiently. It's a mere shuffle.

Comment: ys....groupBy is efficient in spark,but if we give 1GB or 2 GB data, it stuck....I'm sure about this........